# How to add project name to url in java web

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I developed a spring mvc application using IDEA. I set the application context to "/" so I could access the project without inputting project name. However, when I deploy it by putting .war under tomcat/webapps, I must add the project name to access it. The problem is my url design is like this:

js:

```
$http.post('/validate', $scope.account)
```

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

When I click the button, I'd get this:

```
 Request URL:http://localhost:8080/validate
 Request Method:POST
 Status Code:404 Not Found
```

But I expect a url like http://localhost:8080/{project name}/validate. How can I make it work? Is there a way to add project name to url automatically so that I do not have to make any changes when I deploy the project differently?

Comment: In you application context have you defined any port to use? You should check the start log of the application to see which port are you using and which mappings have been set up.

Comment: Just rename your WAR file to ROOT.war and it will deploy to the ROOT application context. If you don't do that, you will have to make your js context aware and that gets messy.

Comment: @Gergely A I use the default tomcat port 8080

Comment: @Quinton Delpeche Thanks. So is there no way to have an auto-completing on url in either js or java?

Comment: As Onur pointed out, you can use the getContextPath() from the request, but this gets messy when you have to pass it to your view so your JS can use that to build the URL. I had to do it on one project and it wasn't fun ... but it is doable.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to build urls with the current context path as a prefix.
`HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()`

**Related document:**
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application.properties (if not create one under src/main/resources) you can add:

```
server.contextPath={project name}
```

hardcoded or get it from your pom as a maven variable.

So that will produce localhost:8080/{project name}/validate.

Answer (score 0):

For spring boot application, if you have an application.properties (if not create one under src/main/resources) you can add:

server.servlet.context-path=/put_your_desired_path_name

Example:
If previous url is http://locahost:8080/client/all
And the server.servlet.context-path=/InvoiceSystem
Then new url will be http://locahost:8080/InvoiceSystem/client/all

Related Document:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#server-properties

Answer (score 0):

I'd not found any official documentation about **context path** except for  [ServerProperties.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.java).

[image]